# Exception ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I'm getting the following error in my tests `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` when migration to Jakarta EE libraries, what is needed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The JAXB classes has moved to `jakarta` namespace instead of `javax` as part of the [Java EE to Jakarta EE transition](https://jakarta.ee/about/faq/#What_happened_with_javax.%2A_namespace%3F).

You should ad the following dependencies to your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```